# Using Puppeteer to get canvas and run canvas.toDataUrl()

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Im new to Puppeteer. I'm using puppeteer to try to get canvas and run the toDataUrl() method. When I console log what im hoping is the canvas it seems to be getting the correct dom element

```
 _remoteObject: {
    type: 'object',
    subtype: 'node',
    className: 'HTMLCanvasElement',
    description: 'canvas',
    objectId: '-861002856273230536.3.2'
  },
```

but any attempt to run a function using $eval (not sure that is correct?) fails.

```
    const dataUrl = await page.$eval('canvas', (cnv) => {
        return cnv.toDataUrl()
    });
```

Could someone check my code please see what is going on?

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: chromium.launch,
        executablePath:
            process.env.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH ||
            (await chromium.executablePath),
        headless: true,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://qifi.org/');
    await page.focus('#ssid');
    await page.keyboard.type('homebase');
    await page.focus('#key');
    await page.keyboard.type('tubulargagy');
    await page.click('#generate');
    const dataUrl = await page.$$eval('#qrcode + canvas', (cnv) => {
        return cnv.map((canvas) => {
            return {
                data: canvas.toDataUrl(),
            };
        });
    });
    // const data = await page.$('canvas');
    console.log('data', dataUrl);
    // const title = await page.title();
    await browser.close();

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            status: 'Ok',
            page: {
                data: dataUrl,
            },
        }),
    };
};
```

Comment: How does this fail, exactly? What are you trying to accomplish/expecting as output, please?

Comment: `const dataUrl=await page.eval("document.getElementById('qrcode').children[0].toDataURL()")` might work?

Comment: @ggorlen currently data logs an empty array I was expecting for a 64BitArray from running canvas.toDataURL()

Comment: Thanks @The Bomb Squad no joy I get ""Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'document.getElementById('qrcode')' is not a valid selector."

Comment: @James try `page.evaluate` instead of `page.eval` my bad

Answer (score 1):

`#qrcode + canvas` is an incorrect selector. The `<canvas>` is the child of the `#qrcode` element, not the next sibling. You can use `#qrcode canvas` to select the desired element.

There's only one QR on the page so `$$` seems like it should be `$`, although this shouldn't cause a failure. The code looks OK other than the selector mishap.

Here's a minimal, runnable example:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^13.5.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto("https://qifi.org/");
  await page.type("#ssid", "homebase");
  await page.type("#key", "tubulargagy");
  await page.click("#generate");
  console.log(await page.$eval("#qrcode canvas", el => el.toDataURL()));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```